# Binding an event to a COM Interface

Tags: c#, event-handling, com-interop, shdocvw

Background: I'm using the standard WebBrowser control that is part of System.Windows.Forms which is actually a wrapper over the Internet Explorer COM control, in order to use functionality not exposed by the wrapper I'm using the ActiveXInstance property getter and casting it to the underlying COM type (or actually the COM interop class that Visual Studio automatically creates for you when referencing a COM type ~ Interop.ShDocVw.dll).

Now in order to avoid shipping the entire Interop.ShDocVw.dll I'm trying to compile only the salient sections of code for what I want to achieve, so I'm looking at a decompiled Interop.ShDocVw.dll and trying to replicate only those sections of code I need. The odd thing is that the code as decompiled by ILSpy doesn't actually compile, specifically these event accessors fail to compile:

```
[DefaultMember("Name"), ClassInterface((short)0), ComSourceInterfaces("SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2\0SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents\0"), Guid("8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"), TypeLibType(34)]
[ComImport]
public class WebBrowserClass : IWebBrowser2, WebBrowser
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    public extern WebBrowserClass();

    public virtual extern event DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow2EventHandler NewWindow2
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        add;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        remove;
    }

    [DispId(210)]
    public virtual extern string LocationName
    {
        [DispId(210)]
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        get;
    }
}
```

Despite the event accessor being marked as extern the compiler reports "An add or remove accessor must have a body". If I add an empty body them the comiler reports:

> SHDocVw.WebBrowserClass.NewWindow2.add' cannot be extern and declare a body

So what is the correct way to attach an event to a COM implementation?

Answer (score 1):

What if you left off the accessor declarations?

```
public virtual extern event DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow2EventHandler NewWindow2;
```

Comment: That compiles, but there is nowhere to put the 'MethodImpl' COM binding attribute. If I put it on the event declaration then the compiler reports error "Attribute 'MethodImpl' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'constructor, method' declarations."

Comment: An event isn't a method.  The accessors are methods, but I'm pretty sure you don't have to declare them.  The IL decompiler will see those items and output code for them, but I don't think you have to use it.  If you compile it, does your code throw errors when attempting to consume the event?

Comment: I'll give it a try. I think this may well be an issue with the decompiler - I don't see those attributes defined on the add/remove accessors in the decomilation to IL.

Comment: Looks like the COM iterop generated by Visual Studio (using tlbimp) is generated as IL code as some of the attributes are on entities that aren't exposed by the C# syntax, specifically the constructor on a delegate definition (visible when you look at the IL created by the C#). Looking at the WebBrowser control in System.Windows.Forms (which also uses COM interop) they did the event binding a compleltey different way, hence trying to reverse engineer the generated Interop was a bad choice (unless I want to recompile and maage IL source code).